# Comparing date with date in string javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to compare a couple of dates in javascript. First of it, I got froma database. In database it is in date format but after send it in a json file I guess it is just a string.

The second I got it in Date format in javascript. I found this script in javascript:

```
var todayAEJ = new Date();
var ddAEJ = todayAEJ.getDate();
var mmAEJ = todayAEJ.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyyAEJ = todayAEJ.getFullYear();
if(ddAEJ<10){ddAEJ='0'+ddAEJ} if(mmAEJ<10){mmAEJ='0'+mmAEJ} todayAEJ = ddAEJ+'-'+mmAEJ+'-'+yyyyAEJ;
```

ANd it works like a charm.

The other date is like this: 13-01-2014

I tried to compare like this:

```
if(todayAEJ > val.date_End)...
```

But it returns true when today's day is bigger than val.date_End's day. So I cannot use this form when the month is diferent. What can I do in this case?

Comment: use timestamp in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   otherDate = '13-01-2014';
   myDate=myDate.split("-");
   var newDate=myDate[1]+","+myDate[0]+","+myDate[2];
    otherDateTimeStamp = new Date(newDate).getTime();
    todayAEJTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();
    if(todayAEJTimeStamp > otherDateTimeStammp){
      // your code
    }
```

you can even use  `var newDate=myDate[1]+"/"+myDate[0]+"/"+myDate[2];`

Use above code...it will solve your problem!

Iinjoy...

Comment: it doesn't work. I think it is because my custorm date is in this format: dd-mm-yy instead of mm-dd-yy

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `MM-DD-YYYY` format instead of `DD-MM-YYYY` you can use `Date.parse`:

```
var todayAEJTimeStamp = Date.parse(todayAEJ);//Date parse needs `MM-DD-YYYY` format

//if val.date_End is instance of Date
if(todayAEJTimeStamp > val.date_End.getTime()) {
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: I can't. I receive the date from the server and it has that format

Comment: Ok, what is `val.date_End`? String? Data Object?

Comment: it is a string from a json file. I have a json file and I read each row and save it in val, then I read each property value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare them via microtime

```
var date = new Date("11/21/1987 16:00:00");
var milliseconds = date.getTime(); // Compare this milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from timestamp solutions, I would recommend to use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) in any case you want to play with Date object in JS. Date object has pretty odd behaviour in JS, and this library comes in handy.